# Trackpad performance subpar on white Core2Duo MacBook (2008)

Tags: touchpad, macbook

I recently replaced Mint with Ubuntu 17.10 on my white MacBook (2008), Core2Duo 2.4, and the trackpad precision has been quite subpar (got better after switching to xorg on the login screen but it's still not quite there). Are there any drivers to fix this?

Hope you can help me.

Much appreciated

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. I made a new thread for the keyboard question only: https://askubuntu.com/questions/975364/keyboard-issues-on-white-core2duo-macbook-2008

Comment: Also, for a possible duplicate of the trackpad question see the “related questions” section: [Macbook Trackpad very coarse](/q/36298/175814)