# Keyboard issues on white Core2Duo MacBook (2008)

Tags: keyboard, macbook

I recently replaced Mint with Ubuntu 17.10 on my MacBook (2008) and have noticed that some symbol keys are not properly assigned (namely those between shift and Enter and the letter keys).

Can you help me?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could switch to ISO layout instead of default by entering following in a terminal:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/iso_layout
```

Note: rebooting will reset this to default.

If everything works like you expect after this command, you can set it permanently using

```
echo options hid_apple iso_layout=0 | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf
```

followed by

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

and eventually reboot your Mac.

Comment: So I simply paste that in the Terminal?

Comment: Yes, but rebooting will reset this to default. If everything works like you expect after this command, you can set it permanently using `echo options hid_apple iso_layout=0 | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf` followed by `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` and eventually reboot your Mac.